# An application on Riemann removable singularity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

**Suppose$f:  \mathbb{D} \setminus \left \{a_1,a_2  \right \}   \rightarrow \mathbb{D} $ be a holomorphic map.Then find a holomorphic map $g:  \mathbb{D}    \rightarrow \mathbb{D} $ such that f(z) = g(z) $ \forall z \in  \mathbb{D} \setminus \left \{a_1,a_2  \right \} $.**

My Attempt:

Notice that $ \exists r >0   $ such that $f: \mathbb{D} (a_1, r) \setminus \left \{a_1\right \}  \rightarrow \mathbb{D} $ is holomorphic and bounded. SO by Riemann Removable singularity theorem:

- $ \lim_{z\to a_1}$ exists.
- $ 
  g_1(z)\begin{cases}f(z) & z\neq a_1\\\lim_{z\to a_1} f(z) & z = a_1\end{cases}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D} (a_1, r)$

and similarly we can say that $ \lim_{z\to a_1}$ exists.
So does this implies that
$$g(z)\begin{cases}f(z) & z\neq a_1,a_2\\\lim_{z\to a_i} f(z) & z = a_i\end{cases} $$is holomorphic on $ \mathbb{D} $
If so how to state that fact explicitly.

Comment: The identity map on $\Bbb D$ is holomorphic, no matter what $f$ is. Are you missing a requirement on $g$?

Comment: Thankz for pointing out. check the edit.

Comment: ?????  " .... using $f$ ..... ???

Comment: sorry My mistake. I corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that there is a holomorphic $g: \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$ such that $g=f$ on $ \mathbb D \setminus \{a_1,a_2 \}$

(not " using $f$" ....)

Your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you. But can you explain why g(z) is holomorphic

Comment: Consult the proof of the Riemann Removable singularity theorem !